# separate an object into three parts

Tags: javascript

If I have an object like this:

```
var myObj = [

    {'name': 'Mike', 'number' : 'b1' , 'level' : 0 },
    {'name': 'Tom',  'number' : 'b2' , 'level' : 0 }
];
```

How can I create three separate objects like:

```
"names" : 
{
  'name1' : 'Mike',
  'name2' : 'Tom',
..}

"numbers" :
{
  'number1' : 'b1',
  'number2' : 'b2',
..}

"levels" :
{
  'level1' : '0',
  'level2' : '0',
...
}
```

Comment: same property multiple times, only last one will be survive :D  ... `{'name' : 'Mike', 'name' : 'Tom'}` => `{name: 'Tom'}`

Comment: Well keys in a js object need to be unique so when names , numbers 7 levels have same key as property that may not  ve a valid object. You can take a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996135/js-associative-array-with-duplicate-names

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063257/necessity-for-duplicate-keys-in-json-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative solution using `Object.keys` function, ES6 arrow function expression and predefined `parts` object:

```
var myObj = [{'name': 'Mike', 'number': 'b1', 'level': 0},{'name': 'Tom', 'number': 'b2', 'level': 0}],
    parts = {'names': {}, 'numbers': {}, 'levels': {}};

myObj.forEach(function(obj, i){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => (parts[k +"s"][k +(i+1)] = obj[k]));
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(parts, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
{
    "names": {
        "name1": "Mike",
        "name2": "Tom"
    },
    "numbers": {
        "number1": "b1",
        "number2": "b2"
    },
    "levels": {
        "level1": 0,
        "level2": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: :Hello , I opened [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989760/remove-keys-that-start-with-specific-letter),if you are interested.Thanks!

Comment: @George, hello, there's an answer from user @ gurvinder372. Did it help you?

Comment: :Hi and than you very much for your interest.I saw that he updated.Now , only an issue remains to remove the brackets from the result.If he answers that , I am ok .Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the keys and the number of the element iteration as property.

```js
var myObj = [{ 'name': 'Mike', 'number': 'b1', 'level': 0 }, { 'name': 'Tom', 'number': 'b2', 'level': 0 }],
    result = {};

myObj.forEach(function (a, i) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        result[k + 's'] = result[k + 's'] || {};
        result[k + 's'][k + (i + 1)] = a[k];
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: :Thanks!I chose the other answer because it was more flexible.I could use `obj.numbers` for example. (upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

Keys in `JS objects` must be `unique`.

The subsequent declaration of `name : Tom` overwrites your previous one.

**Code :**

```
var newObj = {};
newObj.names = {};
newObj.numbers = {};
newObj.levels = {};

for (var i in myObj) {
newObj.names.name = myObj[i].name;
newObj.numbers.number = myObj[i].number;
newObj.levels.level = myObj[i].level;
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Demo fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/29pb33dj/

**Updated answer with proper keys with index :**

```
var newObj = {};
newObj.names = {};
newObj.numbers = {};
newObj.levels = {};

for (var i in myObj) {
newObj.names[i] = myObj[i].name;
newObj.numbers[i] = myObj[i].number;
newObj.levels[i] = myObj[i].level;
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/29pb33dj/1/