# remove keys that start with specific letter

Tags: javascript

If I have this:

```
var result =  [

    { A: '0', b1: '0' },
    { B: '1', b2: '1' },
    { C: '2', b3: '2' }
];
```

How can I remove the keys that starts with 'b' ? ( and/or the second key/values pair)

So , to have :

```
 result =  [

    { A: '0'},
    { B: '1'},
    { C: '2'}
];
```

and to be able to call like:

`result.letters` ,

```
console.log(result.letters) = 

"letters" : 
{
  'A' : '0',
  'B' : '1',
  'C' : '2',
..}
```

Comment: _"and to be able to call like:

result.letters ,"_ what you mean

Comment: Use array.map(function (obj) { return obj .. });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
result = result.map(function(obj){
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    key.indexOf("b") == 0 && delete obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
})
```

And to call it as `result.letters` instead of directly as `result` make the following modification

```
var letters = result.map(function(obj){
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    key.indexOf("b") == 0 && delete obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
});    
result = { letters: {}};
letters.forEach(function(obj){
  var keyName = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  result.letters[ keyName ] = obj[ keyName ];
});
```

Comment: :Nice,thanks but I want to be able to use sth like: `result.letters` as I say in the post.

Comment: :Almost there!I don't want the brackets in the result.letters as you can see in my post.Is this possible?Thanks!

Comment: If you want to call a function, you need the `()` (parenthesis).

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl sorry, didn't get you. Which function?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl still didn't get you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `String.prototype.startsWith()` function and delete the keys.

```js
var results =  [
  { A: '0', b1: '0' },
  { B: '1', b2: '1' },
  { C: '2', b3: '2' }
];

results.forEach(function(result) {
  for (var key in result) {
    if (key.startsWith('b')) {
      delete result[key];
    }
  }
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(results, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

---

## Edit

Is this what you mean? Make a prototype function? If not, you may need to read up on how functions are defined and executed.

```js
var results =  [
  { A: '0', b1: '0' },
  { B: '1', b2: '1' },
  { C: '2', b3: '2' }
];

Array.prototype.letters = function(letter) {
  return {
    letters : this.map(function(obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(result, key) {
        if (!key.startsWith(letter)) {
          result[key] = obj[key];
        }
        return result;
      }, {});
    })
  };
}

var letters = results.letters('b');

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(letters, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

---

## Let's try this again...

If you want to call the function ***LIKE A PROPERTY***, you need to define it on the object.

This is a HACK, and this would not be used in production code.

```js
var results =  [
  { A: '0', b1: '0' },
  { B: '1', b2: '1' },
  { C: '2', b3: '2' }
];

Object.defineProperty(results, 'letters', {
  value: {
    letters : results.map(function(obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(result, key) {
        if (!key.startsWith('b')) {
          result[key] = obj[key];
        }
        return result;
      }, {});
    })
  }
});

var letters = results.letters;

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(letters, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: :Nice,thanks but I want to be able to use sth like: result.letters as I say in the post.

Comment: What is ***sth*** and why would `result.letters` return an object with the key `letters` ???

Comment: perhaps OP wants this function to be added to Array.prototype? sth means something :p . I think he wants to be able to call it like a function e.g. result.filteroutStringsWithB() etc.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl:I mean something like (sth). I want to create an object named letters which will contain the above info.  `letters : { A:0,B:1...}`

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl:Hello, this produces the same results as the above code.I just wanted the brackets to be removed . Thanks !  ( upvoted)