# Javascript object literal - possible to add duplicate keys?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, is is possible to add duplicate keys in object literal? If it is, then how could one achieve it after the object has been first created.

For example:

```
exampleObject['key1'] = something;
exampleObject['key1'] = something else;
```

How can I add the second key1 without overwriting the first key1?

Comment: Can't. It'll update the value.

Comment: How would you expect to use that?

Comment: @Ville: How would you want to access the value and know which version it is?

Comment: I'm about to generate an xml from that object. And that xml contains elements that have exactly the same name (Though they contain atttributes with different values). Mm.. maybe I need to generate the xml first without those duplicates, and then try to add those duplicate elements later in the process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS associative object with duplicate names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996135/js-associative-object-with-duplicate-names)

Comment: What you have there is not an object literal.  As an object literal, your example would look like: `{ key1: something, key1: something else }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No it is not possible. It is the same as:

```
exampleObject.key1 = something;
exampleObject.key1 = something else; // over writes the old value
```

I think the best thing here would be to use an array:

```js
var obj = {
  key1: []
};

obj.key1.push("something"); // useing the key directly
obj['key1'].push("something else"); // using the key reference

console.log(obj);

// ======= OR ===========

var objArr = [];

objArr.push({
  key1: 'something'
});
objArr.push({
  key1: 'something else'
});

console.log(objArr);
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot duplicate keys. You can get the value under the `key1` key and append the value manually:

```
exampleObject['key1'] = something;
exampleObject['key1'] = exampleObject['key1'] + something else;
```

Another approach is the usage of an array:

```
exampleObject['key1'] = [];
exampleObject['key1'].push(something);         
exampleObject['key1'].push(something else);
```

Comment: I think it's because you cannot just do arithmetic operations with any variable. The user did not specify what type of variable "something" is. However, the array implementation would work.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript having keys with same name will override the previous one and it will take the latest keys valuepair defined by the user.

Eg:

```
var fruits = { "Mango": "1", "Apple":"2", "Mango" : "3" }
```

above code will evaluate to

```
var fruits = { "Mango" : "3" , "Apple":"2", }
```