# How to double the numbers in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, iteration

I want to double the key values in an array of objects and I always end up getting the last key:val in the list. I want to be able to print the whole array of objects doubled their values.

```
doubleArr = [];

function doubleSize (a,b) {
    for(var i in a) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            var doubleObj = {};
            doubleObj[i] = b * a[i];
            var results = doubleObj[i];
            doubleArr.push(results);

        }

    }

    return doubleObj;
}

console.log(doubleSize({1:1,1:2,1:3,1:4,1:5}, 2))
```

I only get `{1:10}`. The goal is to get `{1:2,1:4,1:6,1:8,1:10}`. Thanks.

Comment: You're returning `doubleObj`, not `doubleArr`.

Comment: Your object has only one property, `1`. Duplicate properties overwrite earlier values. Before the object is even passed to the function, it is evaluated to `{ 1: 5 }`.

Comment: @Lee Taylor But still it's not giving me the results I wanted. DoubleArr returns [10]. The goal is to return the array of objects.

Comment: You're using the same key for each object `1`...As @CertainPerformance states, so you only have one object passed to your function.

Comment: To be more precise, he has only one *key-value* pair in the passed object.

Comment: @LeeTaylor so you're saying using the same key is the problem? I should change them to different keys? I tried that and I still end of getting the last key:val pair.

Comment: for a start, you don't have "an array of objects"

Comment: Yes, they are IDs, so they need to be unique.

Comment: type `console.log({1:1,1:2,1:3,1:4,1:5})` to see the problem in glorious detail

Comment: @JaromandaX It only prints the last pair. Why?

Comment: Because 1 is being used as the same ID/key throughout. They have to be unique!

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: This question didn't deserved to be downvoted. I'm still learning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue with your code is that you [cannot have duplicate keys in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790146/javascript-object-literal-possible-to-add-duplicate-keys). Every key in an object must be unique; otherwise, you are essentially redeclaring the value associated with that key over and over (so, naturally, in your example, the key `1` will end up being associated with the last value you assign it: `5`).

However, even if you used an object *without* duplicate keys, you still have the following issues:

- Your `doubleArr` should not be declared in the global scope, but instead within the function; moreover, you don't need an array for what you're doing
- Your code is actually constructing an *array of objects* rather than an object. If you want to return an object, you should build up an object with unique values in your function.

Here's an example of a modified version of your code:

```js
function doubleSize (a,b) {
    var doubleObj = {};
    for(var i in a) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            doubleObj[i] = b * a[i];
        }
    }

    return doubleObj;
}

console.log(doubleSize({1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5}, 2)) // Note the unique keys
```

However, I don't fully understand the need for objects. You could use arrays instead, and then replace all of your code with a simple one-liner using `Array.map`:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var doubledArr = arr.map(x => 2*x) // An arrow function that multiplies each value in the array by 2
console.log(doubledArr)
```

Comment: That's what I've been looking for. I see where I went wrong. Still got lots to learn about objects. Thanks.

Comment: I can do the same with arrays, but I want to be able to them with objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same key for your objects `1`. I am assuming that you don't need objects as they don't provide anything obvious to your code:

*Edit* If you insist on using objects, I have provided the second version also.

```js
function doubleSize (a,b) 
{
    var doubleArr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++) 
    {
        doubleArr.push(a[i]*b);
    }

    return doubleArr;
}

console.log(doubleSize([1,2,3,4,5], 2))

function doubleSize2 (a,b) 
{
    var result = {};
    for(var i in a)
    {
        result[i] = a[i]*b
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(doubleSize2({a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5}, 2))
```

Comment: Yes it does work when I change the keys and return as doubleArr, I get the array of numbers doubled.

Comment: `const doubleSize = (a, b) => a.map(n => n * b)` works too :p

Answer (score 0):

You can't have duplicate keys in an object, you can have an array of objects with the same key though. Something like:

```
function doubleSize (a, b) {
  var out = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    out.push({'1': a[i]['1'] * b});
  }

  return out;
}

console.log(doubleSize([{'1': 1}, {'1': 2}, {'1': 3}, {'1': 4}, {'1': 5}], 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doubleSize (a,b) {
    var midObject = {};
    for(var i in a) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            midObject[i] = b * a[i];
        }
    }

    return midObject;
}
```

console.log(doubleSize({1:1,2:2,3:3,4:4,5:5}, 5))