# How to add object name into array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to ask simple question, how to add object name using javascript

I have try this

```
const data = ["1", "5", "3", "4"]
const obj = this.Tags.reduce((acc,e) => { acc[e] = e; return acc; }, {});
```

but the output, I need to change number with string name

```
{
  1: "1",
  3: "3",
  4: "4",
  5: "5"
}
```

I want the output to be like this, how to do that in javascript ?

```
{
  value: "1",
  value: "3",
  value: "4",
  value: "5"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: do you want json as an output? if then, you can't have duplicate keys

Comment: You ask it "in JavaScript" - does that mean you have it for another language (perhaps Python? just an impression)? If that's the case, consider showing what you are trying to convert.

Comment: yes I need it as json or string.

Comment: need it using javascript not using Pyton lang

Comment: Ok, it was just an impression that you were trying to convert an existing code from another language. Why do you want the output in that particular, nonexisting format? The closest thing that actually exists would look like `[{value:"1"},{value:"2"},...]`

Comment: Your output would end up as `{
  value: "5"
}`

Comment: objects can't have the same key twice or more, I'm wondering how you would use this object

Comment: That's a very confusing question, if you wanted it as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assume you want this:

```js
let _ = '';
const data = ["1", "5", "3", "4"];
const obj = JSON.stringify(data.sort().reduce((acc, e) => {
    _ += '_';
    acc[`${_}value`] = e;
    return acc;
}, {}), null, 2).replace(/_/g, '');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @sinzo so you wanted a string?

Answer (score 1):

The output you want would just be one entry because you can not have dupliceate keys

```
{
  value: "5"
}
```

I assume you actually want an array of objects,

```js
const data = ["1", "5", "3", "4"];
const result = data.map(value => ({ value }));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in short, you can't have duplicate keys in an object, so can't have exactly the output you mentioned (here is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790146/javascript-object-literal-possible-to-add-duplicate-keys) you can read about it). Here is an example how you can dynamically insert a key/value pair. Just change `value${i}` to whatever you need your key name to be.

```js
const data = ["1", "5", "3", "4"]
const obj = data.reduce((acc,e,i) => { 
  acc[`value${i}`] = e; 
  return acc; 
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```

If this is necessary that all of the keys are named `value` I'd suggest using an array of objects instead (it is also mentioned in the thread I linked).