# How to convert a lists of dictionary into to a dictionary in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one list of dictionary

> fieldMappings = [
> {
> "fieldName": "message",
> "fieldValue": "message123"
> },
> {
> "fieldName": "time",
> "fieldValue": "2023-02-01T10:50:30.603Z"
> },
> {
> "fieldName": "hostname",
> "fieldValue": "host1"
> },
> {
> "fieldName": "destination",
> "fieldValue": "45.84.0.11"
> },
> {
> "fieldName": "message",
> "fieldValue": "message123"
> },
> {
> "fieldName": "time",
> "fieldValue": "2023-02-01T10:50:30.603Z"
> },
> {
> "fieldName": "hostname",
> "fieldValue": "host2"
> },
> {
> "fieldName": "destination",
> "fieldValue": "218.92.0.221"
> }   ]

Need to convert this fieldMappings like below

```
fieldData= {
"message": 'message123', 
"time": '2023-02-01T10:50:30.603Z', 
"hostname": 'host1', 
"destination": '45.84.0.11',
"message": 'message123', 
"time": '2023-02-01T10:50:30.603Z', 
"hostname": 'host2', 
"destination": '218.92.0.221'
}
```

How can I get the output as fieldData by using TypeScript?

I have tried with the following code

```
let fieldData:any = {};
fieldMappings.forEach((field) => {
    fieldData.add
  fieldData[field.fieldName]= field.fieldValue;
});
```

but getting output as below:

```
fieldData={
     "message": 'message123', 
    "time": '2023-02-01T10:50:30.603Z', 
    "hostname": 'host2', 
    "destination": '218.92.0.221'
    }
```

Comment: there can't be duplicate keys in the json object. Read https://stackoverflow.com/q/38790146/5621827 for more details

Answer (score 1):

**You can't !**

because awaited output has many time the the key 'message', and has many time the key 'hostname' ...

That object can't exists in JS nor in TS.

Anyway, if you assume that keys are unique :

```
const fieldMappings : Array<{fieldName:string, fieldValue:string}>= [ { "fieldName": "message", "fieldValue": "message123" }, { "fieldName": "time", "fieldValue": "2023-02-01T10:50:30.603Z" }, { "fieldName": "hostname", "fieldValue": "host1" }, { "fieldName": "destination", "fieldValue": "45.84.0.11" }, { "fieldName": "message", "fieldValue": "message123" }, { "fieldName": "time", "fieldValue": "2023-02-01T10:50:30.603Z" }, { "fieldName": "hostname", "fieldValue": "host2" }, { "fieldName": "destination", "fieldValue": "218.92.0.221" } ]

const fieldData : Record<string,string> = {};
for(const fielEntry of fieldMappings){
    fieldData[fielEntry.fieldName] = fielEntry.fieldValue;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(fieldData,null,2))
```

output :

```
{
  "message": "message123",
  "time": "2023-02-01T10:50:30.603Z",
  "hostname": "host2",
  "destination": "218.92.0.221"
}
```

Only one occurence of each key. (the last override previous entry of same name).