# How to get length of duplicate object keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I would like to know how i can count the number of duplicate keys in my object.

My object is "a" and i have got the keys of this object using keys(a)

```
keys(a) = ["name", "key", "com", "com"]
```

How can i find the total number of times "com" exists in the above? I should get a length of 2.

thanks in advance

Comment: What number do you expected from `["foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "baz", "baz"]`?

Comment: well i only want to know how many times "com" exists so in my case 2. if you are wanting foo than 2 also.

Comment: How could your original object have duplicate keys?

Comment: I can assure you that the answer will always be **zero**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that an object can't have duplicate keys (or assuming that your `keys()` function allows for nested objects), and just dealing with the question of how to count how many times a particular value appears in an array, a simple way is just to use the [array `.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then check the `.length` of the resulting array:

```js
var keys = ["name", "key", "com", "com"];
var comCount = keys.filter(v => v === "com").length;
console.log(comCount); // 2
```

If you need to support older browsers that don't do ES6 arrow functions then:

```
keys.filter(function(v) { return v === "com"; }).length;
```

Or wrapped in a custom function if you need to do this a lot:

```js
function countValueInArray(val, arr) {
  return arr.filter(v => v === val).length;
}

var keys = ["name", "key", "com", "com"];

console.log(countValueInArray("com", keys));  // 2
console.log(countValueInArray("abc", keys));  // 0
console.log(countValueInArray("key", keys));  // 1
```

Or you could manually code a `for` loop. Or use `.reduce()`. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, JavaScript objects cannot have duplicate keys. The keys must all be unique. There is a good [thread on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996135/js-associative-array-with-duplicate-names) on this topic.

If suppose you have array of objects its possible. Use another object as a counter, like this

```js
var db = [
        {Id: "1" , Player: "Nugent",Position: "Defenders"},
        {Id: "2", Player: "Ryan",Position: "Forwards"},
        {Id: "3" ,Player: "Sam",Position: "Forwards"},
        {Id: "4", Player: "Bill",Position: "Midfielder"},
        {Id: "5" ,Player: "Dave",Position: "Forwards"},
        {Id: "6", Player: "Bill",Position: "Midfielder"}
]

var counter = {};
for (var i = 0; i < db.length; i += 1) {
    counter[db[i].Position] = (counter[db[i].Position] || 0) + 1;
}

for (var key in counter) {
    if (counter[key] > 1) {
        console.log("we have ", key, " duplicated ", counter[key], " times");
    }
}
```