# Jquery add duplicate array key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to create a javascript (jquery) array with duplicated key name like next one

```
{
    "apple": "type1",
    "apple": "type2",
}
```

Here is my current code I stack with

```
var data = {};
jQuery.each(formData, function(i, field) {
    data[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

In above example `field.name` is `"apple"` have different values like `"type1"` or `"type2"`.

With my current code when same `field.name` in `jQuery.each` I got removed/erased `"apple":"type1"`

Comment: Object keys are unique, one key cannot store two values. Use an array, or an array of objects for this matter.

Comment: why not do it like { "apple"  : ['type1' , 'type2'] }

Comment: It's an expected behavior since object keys are unique, If you want to have different values for the same key, you can use an array as a value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS associative object with duplicate names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996135/js-associative-object-with-duplicate-names)

Comment: @Kevin.a because I have limitations by software, I can't rebuild it to use correct array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a jQuery problem, but rather it is to do with the nature of objects in javascript. You can't store multiple values on the same key (how would you access them?).

What you can do is store an array on a key, and add to that:

```js
const formData = jQuery('input');
let data = {};

jQuery('button').click(function() {
  data = {}
  jQuery.each(formData, function(i, field) {
    data[field.name] = data.hasOwnProperty(field.name)
      ? [...data[field.name], field.value]
      : [field.value]
  });
  
  console.dir(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="a" />
<input name="b" />
<input name="b" />
<button>Test</button>
```

What the above code does is use an array against a key, and add to that array for each item.

You can do this without jQuery, and without an `each`, you may or may not prefer this option:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const getAll = selector => Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll(selector)
);

let data = {};

button.onclick = () => {
  data = getAll('input')
    .reduce((result, element) => ({
      ...result,
      [element.name]: result.hasOwnProperty(element.name)
        ? [...result[element.name], element.value]
        : [element.value]
    }), {})
    
  console.dir(data)
}
```

```html
<input name="a" />
<input name="b" />
<input name="b" />
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: This breaks on multiple clicks, but I get the gist of it. Moving the object declaration inside the button click will fix this

Comment: @Kobe very true, good spot, thanks for that. Answer updated now

Comment: you are right but I was limited by software form which incorrectly allow to have inputs with same id/name but different values. Anyway your answer help me.

Comment: what three ```...``` mean in the ```[...data[field.name]```?

Comment: This is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It 'spreads' out the existing contents of that array into a new array.