# Create an Object where the key is the same and the values are from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, key-value

Is there a way for me to create an object where the key is the same and the values are set from an array.

I want the `key = data` and value to be set from an array.

```
key = data
arr = ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz']
```

I need my object to be:

```
my_obj = [{data: 'abc'}, {data: 'pqr'}, {data: 'xyz'}]
```

I am not sure how to create such an object.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. A key must be unique. Given your requirements, why could you not just use `my_obj = { data: ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz'] };`?

Comment: No, JavaScript objects cannot have duplicate keys. The keys must all be unique. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996135/js-associative-object-with-duplicate-names

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS associative object with duplicate names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996135/js-associative-object-with-duplicate-names)

Comment: I edited my question. I meant an array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), something like:

```js
let arr = ['abc', 'pqr', 'xyz']

let my_obj = arr.map(e => ({ data: e }))

console.log(my_obj[0].data) // 'abc'
console.log(my_obj[1].data) // 'pqr'
console.log(my_obj[2].data) // 'xyz

console.log(my_obj)
```

Comment: To use the string assigned to the `key` variable as the key of the object, you can use `arr.map(e => ({ [key]: e }))`. See https://codeburst.io/using-javascript-variables-as-object-keys-c191e2458fa3

Comment: I'm not sure we want a computed property name in this case, OP seems to want just `data`.

Comment: I saw "I want the `key = data`..." in the question and thought a computed property name was required.

Comment: Got it, I think the OP literally meant the object keys to be `"data"` :)